# CSS tags display in top-right screen corner of browser upon load or refresh

Tags: css, html, performance, browser

On my home-page do I have a selection of blogposts in Masonry style with infinite scroll. Each blogpost is a DIV and has an image, author, introduction text, date, etc. 
Also does it have a "category tag", such as "sports", "news", etc., which is displayed on top right corner of each blogpost. See image... [![Image-2][1]][1]

The problem is that when the page loads in browser or re-freshes, that in the top-right corner of the screen ALL these "tags" display for a few seconds. See image ... [![Image-1][2]][2]
But then after everything is loaded, the tags are where they are supposed to be. So there is nothing wrong with positioning.

Is it possible to fix that the "tags" do not show in top-right screen corner of browser for a few seconds when the page loads or you re-fresh? P.S. I do not want to implement a pre-loader, it is no good for user experience and I think overkill for just some tags.

Cannot be anything wrong with my code, I guess, but here my CSS anyway:

```
.tag {
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:'Droid Serif';
    font-style:bold;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    margin-left:15px;
    border:2px solid #FFF;
    padding:6px;
    background-color:#C9C9C9;
    float:right;
    z-index:3;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: Do you have some javascript in the page too?

Comment: @John Bupit - yes, for infinite scroll. Could it there be the problem?

Comment: You are absolutely positing `.tag` but, I assume, you haven't positioned an ancestor so `.tag` is positioned relative to `body`. Masonry adds `position: absolute` to the grid items when it loads which is why you see `.tag` snap into place.  tl;dr Add `position: relative;` to your grid items.

Comment: @Sexy Turnip - Sexy Turnip - Thank you! you are right about the solution, but I cannot fix it with your suggestion... I opened a new post... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31940231/position-div-inside-div-in-top-right-corner-and-not-use-positionabsolute