# Position div inside div in top-right-corner and not use position:absolute

Tags: html, css

I want to position a DIV in the top-right-corner inside a DIV (inside the blue area). I used `position:absolute` to illustrate, but the solution CAN NOT have `position:absolute` for the "tag" DIV because I use Masonry and this adds `position:absolute` to my grid items and when I use it also the layout upon load or re-fresh of page gets messed up for a few seconds. Is it possible to achieve my objective? Again, I cannot implement `position:absolute` for .tag.

Fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rabas007/hf1db9go/7/)

HTML:

```
<div class="article">
    <article class="box">
        <div class="masonry_item_inner">
            <div class="blogpost">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
            </div>
            <div class="tag">MY TAG HERE</div>
                <div class="title">BIG Headline</div>
                <div class="summary">This is about This is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is about</div>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tag {
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    min-height: 0px;
}

.tag {
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:'Droid Serif';
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    margin-left:15px;
    padding:6px;
    background-color:red;
    float:right;
    z-index:3;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
}

.box {
    width: 400px;
    padding: 40px;
    background-color:blue;
}

.title {
    color:green;
    background-color:white;
    font-style:40px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Comment: What about the `position: fixed;` ? You also could play with negative `margin`s but this is fairly tricky / easily breakable in that situation.

Comment: @RedBeast - tried that, didnt work. True about margins so I rather not.

Comment: If the main container height and width are static then you can use top and right margin :)

Comment: _"but the solution CAN NOT have position:absolute for the "tag" DIV because I use Masonry and this adds position:absolute to my grid items"_ why does this stop you using `position: absolute`? It makes no sense. As i mentioned in your previous question, you need to give an ancestor of `.tag` a `position: relative;` ... example: http://jsfiddle.net/hf1db9go/12/ - This will have no negative effect on Masonry.

Comment: @Sexy Turnip - thanks, you solved it for me.

Comment: here is an example with masonry just for good measure ... http://jsfiddle.net/hf1db9go/13/

Comment: @Sexy Turnip - thank you for solving my problem and sorry I didnt understand your solution immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check this code..its working
Fiddle Here- http://jsfiddle.net/hf1db9go/10/

HTML

```html
<div class="article">
    <article class="box">
        <div class="tag">MY TAG HERE</div>
       
        <div class="masonry_item_inner">
            <div class="blogpost">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
            </div>
           
            <div class="title">BIG Headline</div>
            <div class="summary">This is about This is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is about</div>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.masonry_item_inner{
     position:relative;
     float:left;
     left:30px;
}
 .tag {
     top: 0px;
     right: 0px;
     min-height: 0px;
}
 .tag {
     font-size:14px;
     font-family:'Droid Serif';
     text-align:center;
     color:#FFF;
     margin-left:15px;
     padding:6px;
     background-color:red;
     float:right;
     z-index:3;
     display:block;
     position:relative;
}
 .box {
     width: 400px;
     background-color:blue;
     display:inline-block;
     position:absolute;
}
 .title {
     color:green;
     background-color:white;
     font-size:40px;
     font-weight:bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hf1db9go/8/).

I placed `.tag` before `.masonry_item_inner` and edited `.box {padding: 0px 0px 40px 40px;}` for the *bottom*, and *left* padding, and gave `.masonry_item_inner {padding: 40px 40px 0px 0px;}` for the *top* and *right* padding.

Answer (score 0):

For using margin you can fixed it.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/hf1db9go/9/)

```css
.tag {
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    min-height: 0px;
}

.tag {
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:'Droid Serif';
    text-align:center;
    color:#FFF;
    margin-left:15px;
    padding:6px;
    background-color:red;
    float:right;
    z-index:3;
    display:block;
    margin-top: -194px;
    margin-right: -40px;
  /*  position:absolute; */
}

.box {
    width: 400px;
    padding: 40px;
    background-color:blue;
}

.title {
    color:green;
    background-color:white;
    font-style:40px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="article">
    <article class="box">
        <div class="masonry_item_inner">
            <div class="blogpost">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
            </div>
            <div class="tag">MY TAG HERE</div>
                <div class="title">BIG Headline</div>
                <div class="summary">This is about This is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is aboutThis is about</div>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

This will well only if the `.box` height and width are fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have fixed height and width for box.